# Typeorm eager loading not working for MxN relationships while utilizing lazy loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

Problem statement,
Would like to create a Product entity which would be mapped to a lot of other entities(relationships), and allow Lazy loading(as in when required situation).
so in the Product entity the ProductCertificateMapping entity is  wrapped within a Promise.

at the time of lazy loading the productCertificateMapping the Certificate Entities is to be eagerly loaded.
Since the entity ProductCertificateMapping would make more to be present along with the values from the Certificate Entity (3rd table)

Product Entity, 1st level ORM object

```
@Entity("products", { schema: "catalog" })
export class Products extends BaseEntity {
/* rest of the attributes*/
@OneToMany(
() => ProductCertificateMapping,
(productCertificateMapping) => productCertificateMapping.product
)
productCertificateMappings: Promise<ProductCertificateMapping>;
}
```

ProductCertificateMapping entity, 2nd level ORM object (also the MxN table)

```
@Entity("product_certificate_mapping", { schema: "catalog" })
export class ProductCertificateMapping extends BaseEntity {
/* rest of the attributes*/
@ManyToOne(
() =\> Certificate,
(certificate) => certificate.productCertificateMappings,{eager:true}
)
@JoinColumn([{ name: "certificate_id", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
certificate: Certificate;

@ManyToOne(() => Products, (products) => products.productCertificateMappings)
@JoinColumn([{ name: "product_id", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
product: Products;
}
```

Certificate entity, 3rd level object

```
@Entity("certificate", { schema: "catalog" })
export class Certificate extends BaseEntity {
/* rest of the attributes*/

@OneToMany(
() => ProductCertificateMapping,
(productCertificateMapping) => productCertificateMapping.certificate
)
productCertificateMappings: ProductCertificateMapping[];
}
```

Problem statement,
what to create Product entity which is mapped to a lot of other entities to allow Lazy loading for developer(as in when required situation).
so Product entity the ProductCertificateMapping entity is also wrapped with a Promise
at the same time since the entinty ProductCertificateMapping would make sense along with the 3rd table.

Expectation
Product table to load only with its own table attributes (no eager loading) --1st level
Product table's relationships to be loaded using promises(lazy) 2nd --level
and at the same time for Product table's relationship which are of MxN realtionship and have 3d tables, these relationship to be eagerly loaded with 3rd level table data as well.

level 1 entities set with Promises
level 2 entities set without promises and marked as eager:true in ManyToOne

Client Code

```
const prod = ProductRepo().findOne()[];
const certificates = await prod.productCertificateMappings;
console.log(certificates[0].certificateName) //should display the certificatename from the 3rd table.
```

Comment: the MxN table also has 1 additional attribute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.